# How to import keras.engine.topology in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to import keras.engine.topology in Tensorflow.
I used to add the word tensorflow at the beginning of every Keras import if I want to use the Tensorflow  version of Keras.

For example: instead of writing:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input
```

I just write the following code and it works fine :

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input
```

But that's not the case for this specific import:

```
from tensorflow.keras.engine.topology import Layer, InputSpec
```

And I m getting the following error message:

```
No module named 'tensorflow.keras.engine'
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can import `Layer` and `InputSpec` from TensorFlow as follows:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer, InputSpec
```

**UPDATE:** 30/10/2019

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, InputSpec
```

Answer (score 7):

In the `keras_vggface/models.py` file, change the import from:

```
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
```

to:

```
from keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs
```

Comment: It's now `tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils`

Answer (score 2):

In order to import `keras.engine` you may try using:

```py
import tensorflow.python.keras.engine
```

Note: But from `tensorflow.python.keras.engine` you cannot import `topology`

Answer (score 1):

In the `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_vggface/models.py` in `<module>` file...

Change this:

`keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs`

To:

`keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs`

Reason:

If you use the old module, you may encounter an error like `module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the import from from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs to from keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs