# 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.base_layer_v1'' when running PyInstaller .exe file

Tags: python, keras, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable version of python script that predicts images using `.h5` file. The file runs completely fine when on its own in the virtual environment. But when I run the exe after completing the hidden imports following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830206/pyinstaller-created-exe-file-can-not-load-a-keras-nn-model) and data addition in `.spec` file, when I run the exe it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "onefile.py", line 11, in <module>
  model = load_model('complex_model.h5')
File "keras\saving\save.py", line 201, in load_model
File "keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 180, in load_model_from_hdf5
File "keras\saving\model_config.py", line 59, in model_from_config
File "keras\layers\serialization.py", line 159, in deserialize
File "keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 668, in deserialize_keras_object
File "keras\engine\sequential.py", line 490, in from_config
File "keras\engine\training.py", line 195, in __new__
File "keras\utils\version_utils.py", line 61, in __new__
File "keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 1181, in __getattr__
File "keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 1172, in _load
File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.base_layer_v1'
```

I added `import keras.engine` in the following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337558/how-to-import-keras-engine-topology-in-tensorflow). The python file on it's own still runs well.
However, there are no issues during the creation of `.exe` file with `pyinstaller onefile.spec` command:

```
90 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.4
90 INFO: Python: 3.8.5 (conda)
90 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
90 INFO: UPX is not available.
90 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['path',
'path']
100 INFO: checking Analysis
360 INFO: checking PYZ
490 INFO: checking PKG
490 INFO: Bootloader path\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
490 INFO: checking EXE
500 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "path" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)y
On your own risk, you can use the option `--noconfirm` to get rid of this question.
2650 INFO: Removing dir C:\Users\ashah\models\Deeplens\Emotions\standalone\dist\onefile
3480 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
13630 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Here is a part of `.spec` that was changed:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hidden_imports = collect_submodules('h5py') + collect_submodules('tensorflow_core')
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['onefile.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\ashah\\models\\Deeplens\\Emotions\\executable'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('complex_model.h5','.')],
         hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```

Running out of ideas on how to proceed and get the exe working. I can post the .py code if needed. Any help would be golden. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error is caused by `keras` in particular, I replaced it with `tensorflow.keras.*` and seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you replace it in your .py source file? Or did you add it as a hidden import?

Comment: @Aelius I changed it in the ```.spec``` file

Comment: @abhishah901 What did you change in the `.spec` file? I don't have anything that could correspond to `keras` or `tensorflow.keras.*`

Comment: @AlexZab I previously had ```collect_submodules('keras')``` instead of ```collect_submodules('tensorflow_core')```. Tensorflow comes with keras within itself so it takes care of that. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but the error code was

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1'
```

Resolved it by adding hidden import, either in `.spec` file:

```
hiddenimports=['tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1'],
```

or while compiling `.exe` :

```
--hidden-import=tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1
```